# How to specify desired tag name when dynamically creating angular 2 component with attribute selector?

Tags: angular

I have component with attribute selector

```
@Component({selector:'[some-attr]'})
```

When I'm dynamically creating it with component factory in ViewContainerRef, it's getting created like

```
<div some-attr></div>
```

Is there way to specify another tag, instead of div?

Comment: If you always need the same tag name e.g. (section) adjust the selector to the following --> selector: 'section[some-attr]'. It will automatically add a section tag with the attribute "some-attr". 
If you need to add it dynamically take a look at the create method: 
https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory#create
Specifically the parameter rootSelectorOrNode. Haven't tested it but sounds promising.